# Pandas conversion from object to boolean always returns True using astype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe that I need to convert from object to boolean. However, the value changes from `False` to `True` when using `astype`. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

`df['isgood']` returns:

```
0    True
1    False
2    False
```

`df['isgood'].astype(bool)` returns:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The True and False in your df type is str, if you need convert it to bool type

```
df.isgood=='True'
Out[420]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: isgood, dtype: bool
```